# IE and Chrome won't browse the internet on dial up but firefox will. How could I fix it?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

First let me say I've done plenty of troubleshooting and will try to explain as clearly and as much as I can. Please bear with me.

I have a client's computer who uses dial-up and Windows XP. The problem is when I connect to the dial up ISP. IE or Chrome will not browse the internet. It says page cannot be displayed. but if I use firefox on the dialup connection it works. Sounds simple enough there has got to be something wrong with the proxy settings or something...well, that's what I thought here is the weird part.

When connected to the LAN in my office IE, Chrome, and FF all work.

I upgraded to ie8 and the issue still happens. How would you go about troubleshooting this issue? What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a out of date people PC dialer. That was checking a proxy box in internet explorer causing it to mess up. I created a manual connection to people pc bypassing the auto dialer they created to find this. After I explained my findings they said that version was out of date and sent the customer a new cd. All is well now. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses the same connection and proxy settings as Internet Explorer. (The Chrome options box just has a button that brings up the Internet Options window to the Connections tab.) So you can probably focus on what's different between Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Be aware that the Internet Options window Connections tab has separate proxy settings for the dial-up connection and the LAN connection. (The Settings button in the middle will change proxy settings for the selected dial-up connection in the list. The LAN settings button at the bottom is only for LAN connections.)

If there's no obvious proxy, perhaps there's some other hidden or corrupt setting that the Internet Options Connections tab is applying to the the dial-up connection and not to the LAN connection. Try deleting then re-creating the dial-up connection. Or create a new connection with a different name, but the same phone number and log in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would try fiddler2 to see what connections are being attempted.  This may shed some light.
Fiddler is nice because it is external to the browsers so you can compare apples to apples.  All browsers also have add-ons that do the same thing, but with fiddler you can look at cross browser issues with ease.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you try to disabling antivirus and firewall ? If not, do it...
2. Is the issue still present in safe mode with network support?
3. If the two first step doesn't help, you could try the following command line, one by one followed by a test. 
   (In a command prompt runned as administrator)

   **netsh winhttp reset proxy**
   reset proxy settings (remove any proxy)

   **netsh winsock reset**
   repair winsock It removes all Winsock LSP (Layered Service Providers) previously installed, including the potential malfunctioned LSP that causes loss of network packets transmission failure. So all previously-installed LSPs (antivirus/firewall) may need to be reinstalled

   **netsh interface reset all**
   reset all interfaces: 6to4, HTTPSTunnel, ipv4, ipv6, isatap, portproxy, tcp, teredo
   But I don't know exactly what you risk to do it (not much I think, except reinstalling/reconfiguring network related software & windows parameters...)

   (There's also **netsh int ip reset intipreset.log** to reset the TCP/IP stack = reset/rewrite the TCP/IP-related registry keys, but I don't think that could help in this case)

Comment: No dice :-( I just got off of the phone with the ISP. They say it isn't their connection it's internet explorer. They want me to downgrade to ie6 I am not. They don't understand the concept of it working on the LAN but not their Dial up Connection. I will post back with reports.